# Why does joining paths completely replace the original path in Rust?

Tags: rust, filepath

I don't understand how Rust concatenates file paths. Why doesn't this work:

```
fn main() {
    let root = std::path::Path::new("resources/");
    let uri = std::path::Path::new("/js/main.js");
    let path = root.join(uri);
    assert_eq!(path.to_str(), Some("resources/js/main.js"));
}
```

fails with:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `Some("/js/main.js")`,
 right: `Some("resources/js/main.js")`', src/main.rs:5:5
```

I see in [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html) that "pushing an absolute path replaces the existing path", but this seems like a terrible idea that will catch a lot of people.

In that case, how do I safely strip the absolute path, or make it relative?

Comment: I guess you can see this: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/16507 discussion

Comment: @Stoogy thanks; I've commented on the issue.

Answer (score 9):

This is because `"/js/main.js"` is treated as an absolute path ([doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.push))

> If path is absolute, it replaces the current path.
>
> On Windows:
>
> - if `path` has a root but no prefix (e.g. \windows), it replaces everything except for the prefix (if any) of `self`.
> - if `path` has a prefix but no root, it replaces `self`.

If you change your example to `"js/main.js"` and then use `join`, it will be properly constructed ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=c87da10dc1631f6ba83f58b998c490e3))

Comment: Thanks, then how do I treat the incoming path as always relative?

Comment: FYI: `os.path.join` has the same behavior in Python. I am not sure *why*, but at least there's some consistency there.

Comment: @PetrusTheron I would suggest not using `/` at all. You can omit them completly.

Comment: So...how do I strip the leading slash and ensure that paths are always descendants of a given folder? As you can probably tell from my example, the slash-prefix is coming from a browser. Would also like to avoid parent "../../../../some-secret" files from leaking out.

Comment: I would suggest using a crate ;) https://crates.io/crates/path-absolutize or https://crates.io/crates/path-dedot

Comment: @hellow Wouldn't *path-canonicalize* a more precise name? *absolutize* sounds to me as *Make all paths absolut*

Comment: @TimDiekmann quoting the [doc](https://crates.io/crates/path-absolutize): *"The difference between absolutize and canonicalize methods is that absolutize does not care about whether the file exists and what the file really is."* ;)

Comment: @PetrusTheron you can use [`Path::strip_prefix`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.strip_prefix) to remove the leading `/`: [playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2015&gist=b67cfdcb0ccfa3814a953fa5e0626cd3)

Comment: Adding on to @MatthieuM. 's assertion above about Python, in the C++ [`std::filesystem::path::append`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/append) (it's the equivalent method used to what's happening here), this behavior is also identical.  Don't put leading slashes into your path unless it's an absolute path.

Comment: The current answer to the question "Why ..." is like: "because it was written this way" ("because /js is treated as absolute => according to docs it replaces"). Answers like these do not answer the question. It just re-states what was already known.